# Permissões de usuário no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-functions

Bom dia, estou com uma dúvida, estou montando um app onde a pessoa acessa ele, faz o login e senha e depois aparece a tela inicial do mesmo. caso a pessoa não tenha cadastro ela fara o cadastro através do proprio app, mas minha preocupação é a seguinte. quero criar uma regra onde somente determinado usuário pode criar esses usuários. ex: a diretora da escola cria o usuário com base nos dados do aluno, ex: RA(REGISTRO DO ALUNO), mas queria saber como faço essa regra, se é diretamente no banco de dados FIREBASE no painel web, ou via app mesmo no androidstudio, e dependendo qual seria a escolha, como faria isso ?

Comment: Como você estruturou o banco de dados? Pode postar a estrutura aqui? Assim eu poderei te ajudar a fazer as regras.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Como você diferencia os users? Tem um campo que indica que é director/aluno? Se sim, qual é o campo?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode bloquear a `Activity` de cadastro para quem não tiver a permissão para cadastrar o usuário. Se for só um usuário como você escreveu pode fazer assim

```
  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
  String userId = user.getUid();

  if(userId.equals("id permitido")){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, CadastroActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  } else {
      //É sempre importante avisar ao usuário o que está acontecendo
      Toast.makeText(this, "Apenas usuários autorizados podem cadastrar novos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: Boa ideia, muito obrigado!

Comment: Isso só é uma boa ideia se usado em conjunto com uma regra de segurança no painel do Firebase, porque qualquer um pode alterar seu APK para abrir a tela de cadastro diretamente e burlar essa verificação. Qualquer verificação do lado do cliente deve ser feita apenas para manter o fluxo da aplicação, não para garantir a segurança.

Comment: Com certeza, eu n inclui isso na resposta pois as regras já vem assim como padrão, mas é de extrema importância controlar quem tem acesso ao banco de dados